# Why does false ÷ true evaluate to false?

Tags: boolean, julia

Booleans in Julia, when used in calculations, have numeric values (`false` = `0`, `true` = `1`).

All of the following have expected results:

```
true + false        #  1
false - true        #  -1
false / true        # 0.0
true ÷ false        # DivideError: integer division error
0 ÷ 1               # 0
```

Except for:

```
false ÷ true        # false
```

So why does `false ÷ true` evaluate to `false`, instead of `0` like `0 ÷ 1` does?

---

**Update**: it appears multiplication has the same behavior:

```
false * true        # false
```

I can understand that there may different behavior for type `Bool` than other numeric types, but it's strange that addition and subtraction behave differently than multiplication and division.

The [Mathematical Operations documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#Boolean-Operators) states:

> Note that Bool is an integer type and all the usual promotion rules and numeric operators are also defined on it.

so it's a little surprising that it doesn't treat booleans as integers in all arithmetic contexts.

Comment: Iirc the ÷ operator is an alias for the `Base.div()` function. **I am not sure** and have never used Julia, but I guess that the div function always tries to return something of the same type as the operands, therefore a boolean. Guess: div internally does bool->int conversion, does the int division and then casts back to boolean. For false÷true that works, for true÷false the integer division step fails.

Comment: Or the Julia compiler wants to answer math problems in as near types as possible, and therefore answers here in boolean values. Technically in a way 0 ÷ 1 is the same as false ÷ true.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as calling `div(false, true)` https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#Division-functions

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl: Your guess is not quite right, the code works entirely in Boolean. Here's the definition: `div(x::Bool, y::Bool) = y ? x : throw(DivideError())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DNF pointed out, the `div()` decision is implemented in Boolean logic.

The specific method definitions are in the base code of the Julia source tree ([`julia/base/bool.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/bool.jl#L184)).

Addition and subtraction convert `Bool` to `Int`:

```
+(x::Bool, y::Bool) = Int(x) + Int(y)
-(x::Bool, y::Bool) = Int(x) - Int(y)
```

but division does not:

```
div(x::Bool, y::Bool) = y ? x : throw(DivideError())
```

I do still find it a bit odd that not all `Bool` operations are treated as numeric types but clearly it's intended to be that way.

Comment: Quite counter-intuitive. In C that would have been UB, meaning printing 'rabbits' is quite valid.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning is that the division of 2 bools is always a bool or error, while other arithmetic on bools can produce numbers outside the range of a bool.

Comment: I've revised the question - multiplication has the same behavior, so it's not just specific to division.

Comment: multiplication has the same answer. all outputs of `Bool*Bool` fit into a `Bool`

Comment: OK, I can see the logic there - division, multiplication, and even exponentiation would result in `0` or `1`, so the result can fix in a `Bool`. Is this behavior documented anywhere? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is documented, and it's a little ad-hoc given that (e.g.) `Int8+Int8=Int8`, but I think the decision was just that with Bool, if you want the version with overflow, it's just xor anyway.